# Find last row , erasing header

Tags: excel, vba

If a2 cell is empty below code erase the header and if i add +1 its keep adding zero

can i find last empty row without erasing header even a2 is empty?
(a1 is header)
Thanks

```
Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row

With Range("a2:a" & lastrow)

End With
```

Comment: You could just add a `+1` to your `lastrow` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more robust alternative to my suggestion in the comments. This way `lastrow` will never be less than 2.

```
Sub x()

Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
lastrow = WorksheetFunction.Max(2, lastrow)
With Range("a2:a" & lastrow)
    .Value = 1
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: exactly as i want